# Why is my google map v3 api code not working correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps v3 api in my web application, and it is working great in Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera but not in Firefox. Basically, what is supposed to happen is the map gets initialized and then markers are placed on the map for any database addresses within the bounds of the map. The map loads quickly in the working browsers (less than 1 second) and the markers are displayed. Firefox takes over 5 seconds to load the map, and I'm thinking that this lag causes the markers to not display. This idea was reinforced by the fact that when I debug my javascript using Firebug, the markers get displayed correctly. I have tried the following:

```
       function InitializeMap() {
            gm = google.maps;
            map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: zoomLevel
            });

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

            oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, { markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true });

            if (!!navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(geolocate);
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('No geolocation support');
            }

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
                CallHandler();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
                CallHandler();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                // Load Markers
                CallHandler();
            });

            //google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
            //    //this part runs when the mapobject is created and rendered
            //    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function () {
            //        //this part runs when the mapobject shown for the first time
            //        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            //        CallHandler();
            //    });
            //});
        }
```

The tiles loaded event did not work either.

Any help on this is appreciated. The CallHandler simply makes an ajax call and returns json.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: use a default-center for the map

Comment: Wow, that worked. Many thanks. So, it was not the map loading that was taking so much time, it was the browser geolocation.